# Changing value of an array inside foreach doesn't effect the array outside of foreach

Tags: conditionals, foreach, loops, readarray

- Editor: TexMaker
- Tex distribution: Latex

I have a foreach statement, and I'm changing some of array cell's values inside of the foreach block.

But it seems that the changes have not applied on the array while I'm using the array after the foreach statement block, and I'm confused why?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\mdata{%
top bottom center top bottom
}

\readarray\mdata\mdataA[1,5]

\def\myvar{2}


\begin{document}
    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {1, ..., 5}{
        \setvalue\mdataA[1,\xi]{something}
        \x . mydata[\xi] = \mdataA[1,\xi] \\
    }

    -------------------------

    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {1, ..., 5}{
        \x . mydata[\xi] = \mdataA[1,\xi] \\
    }
\end{document}
```

The output:

```
1. mydata[1] = something
2. mydata[2] = something
3. mydata[3] = something
4. mydata[4] = something
5. mydata[5] = something
-------------------------
1. mydata[1] = top
2. mydata[2] = bottom
3. mydata[3] = center
4. mydata[4] = top
5. mydata[5] = bottom
```

How can I fix this? I mean, how can I have an array that changes inside foreach statement and have effected globally?

Comment: You're under the impression that the syntax for conditional is `\ifnum<condition>{true}\else{false}\fi`. It isn't: you *must* remove the braces.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. But I found out that without the if-else statement the problem remains the same, so I've edited and simplified my question.

Comment: Sure! You don't take into account that `\foreach` does each step in the loop inside a group.

Answer (score 3):

The code in a `\foreach` loop is performed inside a group. So if you do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\def\testA{A}
\def\testB{B}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x [count=\xi] in {A,B} {%
  \expandafter\edef\csname test\x\endcsname{\xi}%
}

testA is \testA

testB is \testB

\end{document}
```

hoping to get

> testA is 1
> testB is 2

then, sorry, you wouldn't. You'll get

> testA is A
> testB is B

Sorry for the complicated code with `\csname` and `\expandafter`, but this is just a simplified version of what you want to do with `readarray` and has nothing to do with `\ifnum` at all.

I'm not sure if you can *globally* do `\setvalue`. Check the documentation of `readarray`. On the other hand, there are *much* better ways to cope with arrays of data: maybe you should be clearer about what you want to do.

Comment: You're right. If I use `\setvalue` "outside" of any if-else or foreach blocks it will change the array cell globally. But using `\setvalue` "inside" of these blocks I saw no effect on array cell outside of these blocks. But I don't know there is way to cope this like using another package or whatever or not.

Answer (score 1):

I jus added `\global` before `\setvalue` like this:

`\global\setvalue\mdataA[1,\xi]{something}`

Now I can see changes of the array cells outside of the `foreach` or `if-else` blocks too.

I don't know if it's the best way but it was just good enough to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than answer your specific question about the scope of `\foreach` loops, I instead show the way your goal might be accomplished using just the facilities of the `readarray` package itself, by merging arrays.

Here, I set the default cell value of `\initarray` to be bolded `something`.  I can use `\initarray` to create an array of the size I wish to substitute into my "master" array (here `\mdataA`, which I have, by the way, created from a file read rather than from a `\def`).  Then, I can use `\mergearray` to overlay the contents of the `\initarray`ed array on top of the master array.  I demonstrate it twice, so that you can see that a partial row or a complete row can be overlayed.  in fact, an mxn array can be overlayed merely by `\initarray`ing an mxn array, if desired, though I did not show it in my MWE.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{mdata.dat}
 a b c d e
top bottom center top bottom
 f g h i j
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\renewcommand\readarrayinitvalue{\noexpand\textbf{something}}
\begin{document}
\readdef{mdata.dat}\mdata
\readarray\mdata\mdataA[-,\ncols]
\typesetarray\mdataA

\bigskip
\initarray\replacement[1,2]
\mergearray\replacement\mdataA[2,2]
\typesetarray\mdataA

\bigskip
\initarray\replacement[1,5]
\mergearray\replacement\mdataA[2,1]
\typesetarray\mdataA
\end{document}
```

[image]